# Aligning heading tag pseudo element background images on zoom?

Tags: html, css, css-float, pseudo-element

After messing around with pseudo element css for a rather long time I've come up with a solution to the heading tag double ended custom image underline I required using the following code:

```
h2{
clear:both;
position:relative;
color:#000;
margin-left:83px;
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eRq2.png) 0px 16px repeat-x;
font-size:1.5em;
float:left;
padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

h2:after,
h2:before{
content:" ";
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AulCS.png);
display:block;
width:83px;
height:31px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
margin-left:-83px;
margin-bottom:-10px;
z-index:-1;
}

h2:after{
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux1ed.png);
right:0;
left:auto;
margin-right:-83px;
}

<h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
<br>
<h2>Home</h2>
```

Which can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/848s2335/1/

However I've noticed the 3 background images do not appear to stay in line when the page is zoomed in and out. Please could anyone point me in the right direction to keep all three images in line at all times?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use a different centering method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use background image, use border-bottom, this will set the line at the bottom of h2, next set your bottom property of after and before to match with the same position of the border.

Remove this line on your h2:

```
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eRq2.png) 0px 16px repeat-x;
```

Instead add this line:

```
border-bottom: 7px solid #000;
```

In your :before and :after css, change your bottom property to macth with border line:

```
bottom:-9px;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/og8zwpnq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could give the h2 element set height. I added height of 27px and it worked for me in your Fiddle:

```
h2 {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    margin-left: 83px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eRq2.png) 0px 16px repeat-x;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    height: 27px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make the left end stay always in line by:

- setting all elements' `height` to the same value (I used `62px`)
- setting `background-repeat: no-repeat` and `background-position: center` on both ends
- adjusting other values (`padding` etc)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecpv2kv0/

The right end is sill like 0.5px out of line, but probably editing png images to have even height value (right now it's 31px) might help here.